# Workflow using the metric system?

Tags: workflow

I was wondering on what is the best workflow for combining scenes and characters.

Like for example, if you are making a living room scene, should I use the metric system to get the correct measurements on the room and furniture or should I just use blender units?

Because my character is in blender units and my room is in metric, so should I just scale my character down or is there a workflow to make this process streamlined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender units equal one meter.

You can set the scene to explicitly use metric units in the scene>unit section of the properties window:

[image]

Keeping your scene in real world measurements is a good idea when it comes to dealing with physics simulations and lights, blender is designed to calculate things using real world values.